# Как вывести картинку из JSON ,имеющий вложенные объекты?

Tags: android, json

Использовала библиотеку retrofit2.
Вот такой у меня Json (удалила некоторые данные):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как я делаю:

```
 Picasso.with(context).load(String
.valueOf(item.get(position).getMediaPath())).into(pic);
```

Просто  выводит пустой ImageView.

И так делала, чтоб получить URL media:

```
    String Base_url="https://api.booglo.com/";
    String a=Base_url+item.get(position).getMediaPath().getMediPath()+"500x500//"
            +item.get(position).getMediaPath().getExtension();

    Picasso.with(context).load(a).into(pic);
```

С этими всё хорошо:

```
    name.setText(item.get(position).getName());
    price.setText(item.get(position).getPrice());
    mark.setText(item.get(position).getHost().getName());
    reytinq.setText(item.get(position).getHost().getRating());
```

Comment: А как понять к какому виду нужно привести ссылку?

Comment: А вы уверены что по этому адресу есть изображение? у меня например выкидывает ошибку php по адресу https://api.booglo.com/media/products/1/5/1_1519719330.png

Comment: @danilshik  Вот https://api.booglo.com/media/products/1/5/500x500//1_1519719330.png ,но и это не получается.Может из за размера?

Comment: Stringa=Base_url+item.get(position).getMediaPath().getMediPath()+"500x500//"
                +item.get(position).getMediaPath().getExtension();

Comment: По ссылке notFoundHhttpException

Comment: @Романыч  https://api.booglo.com/media/products/1/5/500x500//1_1519719330.png  У меня это открывает

Comment: @Sura что за объект `item`? чем вы разбираете JSON?

Comment: @mit item  List'та .POJO классами,кстати вот эти коды в адаптере у меня(ArrayAdapter)

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте вставить ссылку строкой в `.load()`, и без двойного слеша. Если заработает - проблема либо в двойном слеше, либо где-то теряется что-то, логайте и смотрите чего не хватает

```
.load("https://api.booglo.com/media/products/1/5/500x500/1_1519719330.png")
```

Comment: Не получилось,а другие URL  картинок с интернета работают.